# How to load a local html file into webView on iPad

Tags: xcode4, ipad

I have an iPad Master Detail project and I am trying to display html content in a web view which is called detailWebView.

I have set the content of detailItem in the Master View Controller.

```
self.detailViewController.detailItem=[[_topicsData
                                       objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]
                                      objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];
```

I have tried many ways to get the extracted information to display in the web view but it will not.

In configureView I have:

```
NSString *myString=[_detailItem objectForKey:@"url"];
NSString *myNewString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",myString,@".html"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:myNewString];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[self.detailWebView loadRequest:request];
```

But nothing I try will load the content.

I know I have the correct detail for url because when I try

```
NSLog(@"detailItem is %@",url);
```

I get something like myurl.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the code in `viewDidLoad`:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self. detailWebView.delegate = self;

    NSString *myString=[_detailItem objectForKey:@"url"];
    NSString *myNewString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",myString,@".html"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:myNewString];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [self. detailWebView loadRequest:request];
}
```

Comment: It won't let me put the first line in DetailViewController. It says: Assigning to 'id<UIWebViewDelegate>from incompatible type BSDetailViewController *const__strong.

Comment: If I hard code the url it works fine e.g.[_detailWebView loadRequest:
             [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:
              [NSURL fileURLWithPath:  
               [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"incomeelasticity" ofType:@"html"]
                         isDirectory:NO]
              ]
             ];